# The global hook procedure doesn't work in Windows 11

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to implement two key combinations, `LeftAlt+1` and `LeftAlt+2`, and have them inject character strings. The new hotkeys are implemented by following the DLL.

```
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
HHOOK hHook{ NULL };
const DWORD L1 = 49;
const DWORD L2 = 50;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
    LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code < 0) return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);

    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbdStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        DWORD vkCode = kbdStruct->vkCode;  // virtual-key code
        if (kbdStruct->flags & LLKHF_ALTDOWN && (vkCode == L1 || vkCode == L2))
        {
            if (vkCode == L1) cout << "First text";
            else cout << "Second text";
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

A test application loads the DLL and uses the Win32 function `SetWindowsHookExW()` to install the hook procedure `KeyboardHookProc` *globally*.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HHOOK hhook = 0;

    LPCWSTR dllPath = L"PernumLib.dll";
    static HINSTANCE hinstDLL = LoadLibraryW(dllPath);

    HOOKPROC keyboardHookProc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "KeyboardHookProc");

    hhook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHookProc, hinstDLL, 0);
    if (hhook == NULL)
    {
        cout << "SetWindowsHookExA failure!\n";
        Sleep(3000);
        return -1;
    }

    while (GetMessage(NULL, NULL, 0, WM_KEYLAST));

    //if (hhook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
    return 0;
}
```

It works as long as the two hotkeys are used within the window of the test application. But the idea is to implement the hotkeys *globally*, e.g., to use them when typing in text in a web browser or in a text editor. However, the hotkeys are not available outside the test application.

I realize that a global hook works only with 64-bit applications or 32-bit applications, depending on the architecture of the DLL. I'm developing the DLL using Visual Studio 2022 in Windows 11 on a 64-bit machine, and I believe that the artifacts created by VS are 64-bit (but I haven't verified it). Google Chrome, where the hotkeys don't work, is a 64-bit application. My conclusion is that the problem is not caused by the 32-bit/64-bit inconsistency.

A technically similar example of DLL injection is shown [here](https://cocomelonc.github.io/tutorial/2021/11/25/malware-injection-7.html). The author observes the same problem: *There is a caveat. This technique is not working in my Windows 10 x64 machine. I think the reason is this: CIG block this technique.*

Limiting a global hook procedure to a single test application makes no sense, so there must be a solution. What more do I have to do to make it work?

**EDIT**: Thanks to the comments below and additional tests, I realize that *the hook actually works*. However, since a low-level hook executes in the context of the application calling `SetWindowsHookExW`, the texts are injected into this application even when the hotkeys are typed into a web browser or a text editor. Consequently, to solve my problem, I have to use the hook `WH_KEYBOARD` rather than `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. I'm working on it.

Comment: The assumption that DLL injection is used for this hook is not correct.  The low-level mouse and keyboard hooks do not require or use a DLL.  Otherwise the reason that the GetMessage() loop is necessary, that's how the OS can break in and make the hook callback. 
 If injection is actually what you need to do your deed then it won't work.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Are you suggesting that WH_KEYBOARD would work but not WH_KEYBOARD_LL? In the list of hook types WH_KEYBOARD_LL is shown as global, it cannot be installed locally. But I may try to modify the DLL to use WH_KEYBOARD instead.

Comment: Are you looking for [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey)?

Comment: Hooks don't do *"text injection"*. If that is the problem you need to solve, then hooks aren't the tool to use. That said, I'm sure you like a responsive system. Hooks are the most convenient way to render a perfectly snappy system unresponsive. Have you understood the consequences of using a (low-level) hook? If so, are you open to alternatives that are far less intrusive? In that case, can you explain the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable: I'd like to use two key combinations to inject text that I frequently have to type in. My hook procedure does it perfectly well, but not *globally*. I'm open to alternatives, but I've spent some time studying hook procedures, and I'd like to finalize it. I can definitely use a high-level hook.

Comment: You'll want to decompose your problem into two: `1` Observe arrival of key combinations (that's what `RegisterHotKey` does), and `2` Replace/insert text into the target application ([UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is the standard infrastructure for this).

Comment: @IInspectable: I've had a quick look at this, and I don't think it can work for me. In `RegisterHotKey` you have to identify the window to receive the hotkey. This is quite impossible; I want to inject texts into browsers and editors. This is where globality comes in.

Comment: *"In `RegisterHotKey` you have to identify the window to receive the hotkey"* - Right. [`GetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) will.

Comment: Chrome actively blocks third-party DLLs from being loaded in its process. Maybe see if you can get it to work in another app, e.g. Notepad.

Comment: A low-level keyboard hook [*"is called in the context of the thread that installed it"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)). You do not need to inject a DLL into a foreign process for a low-level keyboard hook. You do not even have to implement the hook procedure in a DLL.

Comment: @IInspectable: `GetForegroundWindow`? no, no, no! If I have to run the injecting application for each foreground window, I prefer to manually type in my frequently used strings. A global hook procedure has the advantage of only needing to be run once, and it applies to all threads. You've already helped me twice; aren't you a hook procedure expert as well who could assist me with this?

Comment: @IInspectable: I know that you don't need a DLL for `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. But I don't think it's harmful. A hook procedure for `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` can only be set globally, so it **should** work for all apps, but it doesn't.

Comment: A low-level keyboard hook doesn't run for a given process, or window, or thread. By the time the system calls into the hook procedure, the (prospective) recipient of the keyboard input hasn't been evaluated. Injecting the hook procedure DLL into a process doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter: That's too bad; I'm doing it mostly for Chrome. Other browsers, hopefully, will be less hostile. I've tried my hook procedure in Notepad; it doesn't work. But I'm not convinced you are right. The app AutoHotkey does basically the same thing, and it does work with Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook procedure must use hook `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. It does not work with the hook `WH_KEYBOARD`. The reason is that a hotkey using `ALT` must be caught early and stopped from proceeding further into the system.

Consequently, the main program shown above is correct.

An example of a hook procedure is shown below. It detects the hotkeys `LeftAlt+Q` and `LeftAlt+A` and injects the string `AB12` in both cases, using the WinAPI function `SendInput()`, to emulate signals sent by the keyboard driver. The emulated keyboard actions are in order: `LeftAlt` `up`, `Shift` `down`, characters `AB`, `Shift` `up`, characters `12`, `LeftAlt` `down`. Additionally, the train of keyboard actions starts and ends with `CTRL` `down`/`up`. These actions must be added to ensure a stable operation of the hook procedure. Their role is probably to add delay.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void DisplayString()
{  
    INPUT in[16] = {0};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(in); i++) in[i].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    i = 0;
    in[i++].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;    // CTRL
    in[i].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;      // CTRL Up
    in[i++].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    in[i].ki.wVk = VK_LMENU;        // LeftAlt Up
    in[i++].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    in[i++].ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;     // LeftShift down
    in[i++].ki.wVk = 'A';
    in[i].ki.wVk = 'A';
    in[i++].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    in[i++].ki.wVk = 'B';
    in[i].ki.wVk = 'B';
    in[i++].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    in[i].ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;    // LeftShift Up
    in[i++].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    in[i++].ki.wVk = '1';
    in[i].ki.wVk = '1';
    in[i++].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    in[i++].ki.wVk = '2';
    in[i].ki.wVk = '2';
    in[i++].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    in[i++].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;    // CTRL
    in[i++].ki.wVk = VK_LMENU;      // LeftAlt Down
    in[i].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;      // CTRL Up
    in[i++].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(in), in, sizeof(INPUT));
}

HHOOK hHook{ NULL };

#define     VK_HOT_1        0x51
#define     VK_HOT_2        0x41

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code < 0) return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);

    // If LeftAlt pressed
    if (wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN && (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LMENU) & 0x80000000))
    {
        DWORD vkCode = ((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->vkCode;  // virtual-key code
        if (vkCode == VK_HOT_1 || vkCode == VK_HOT_2)
        {
            DisplayString();
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The (array of) struct `INPUT` with the keyboard actions contains a union and cannot be easily initialized using a list of values enclosed in braces. The unconventional way of indexing elements in `INPUT in[16]` allows for adding and removing keybaord actions from the sequence without the need to renumber the actions following the change.

Some commentators suggested using UI Automation to solve this problem. UI Automation is an add-on to .NET WinForms and is quite complex compared to the presented solution. Moreover, UI Automation cannot be used with all Windows controls. In contrast, the presented solution emulates keyboard input and works with any control able to receive characters.