# How to make a hook procedure to work globally

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, hook

I want special key combinations to inject fixed character strings into web browsers and text editors. I'm trying to implement it using a hook procedure triggered by the hook `WM_KEYBOARD`. The code below shows the hook procedure. It responds to the keys `LeftAlt+Q` and `LeftAlt+A` with strings `S1` and `S2`. It is implemented as a DLL.

```
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
HHOOK hHook{ NULL };

#define     VK_HOT_1        0x51
#define     VK_HOT_2        0x41
const string S1 = "First string";
const string S2 = "Second string";

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code < 0) return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);

    WORD keyFlags = HIWORD(lParam);
    BOOL isKeyReleased = (keyFlags & KF_UP) == KF_UP;
    BOOL altDown = (keyFlags & KF_ALTDOWN) == KF_ALTDOWN;
    WORD vkCode = wParam;

    if (isKeyReleased && (vkCode == VK_HOT_1 || vkCode == VK_HOT_2) && altDown )
    {
        SHORT lAltState = GetKeyState(VK_LMENU);
        BOOL lAltDown = (lAltState & HSHELL_HIGHBIT) == HSHELL_HIGHBIT;
        if (lAltDown)
        {
            if (vkCode == VK_HOT_1) cout << S1;
            else cout << S2;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The hook procedure is installed using the Win32 function `SetWindowsHookExW()`.

```
int hook()
{
    HHOOK hhook = 0;

    LPCWSTR dllPath = L"PernumLib.dll";
    static HINSTANCE hinstDLL = LoadLibraryW(dllPath);
    if (hinstDLL == NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Loading DLL failed!", NULL,
            MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_APPLMODAL);
        return -1;
    }

    HOOKPROC keyboardHookProc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "KeyboardHookProc");

    hhook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_KEYBOARD, keyboardHookProc, hinstDLL, 0 );
    if (hhook == NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Installing hook failed!", NULL,
            MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_APPLMODAL);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the last argument in the call to `SetWindowsHookExW()` is `0`. Then, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa), *the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread*. I understand that the hook procedure is associated with all running desktop apps on the PC.

However, in my tests, only the calling application recognized the hotkeys and reacted as expected. All the other desktop applications do not recognize the hotkeys and either do nothing or beep as an illegal key warning.

The hook procedure is not installed globally; it works solely in the calling application. What more do I have to do to make it work as required?

**Background info**

I've also tested an implementation using the hook [`WM_KEYBOARD_LL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75581364/the-global-hook-procedure-doesnt-work-in-windows-11). Then, the hook is installed globally and recognized by other applications on the PC. However, the hook procedure is executed in the context of the calling application, and the text strings are injected into this application.

The app `AutoHotkey` implements special key combinations. It may be configured with arbitrary actions on arbitrary hotkeys. It can also inject text strings into desktop apps. But for now, I prefer to develop my own application. `AutoHotkey` uses the hook `WM_KEYBOARD_LL` along with the function `RegisterHotkey()`.

**EDIT**: Following the comments below, I added a `MessageBox` to the hook procedure. *It does pop up when a hotkey is pressed in any desktop application*. So the global installation of the hook works as expected. But my attempt to insert text strings is inadequate and must change. I'll study the [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) as suggested by [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable).

Comment: Two issues. First, `hHook` global variable in the DLL is never initialized and remains NULL. `hhook` local variable in the `hook` function of the main application is not in any way related to `hHook`. Second, your hook tries to print to `cout` - but `cout` in the DLL is not connected to the standard output of the process the DLL is injected into (which likely doesn't even have a console on which the output may appear). Use `MessageBox` or similar, or write to a file, if you want to observe your hook in action.

Comment: The problem hasn't changed. You literally want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75581364/the-global-hook-procedure-doesnt-work-in-windows-11#comment133346779_75581364). There are two parts to the problem, observing input, and responding to it. They are independent of each other, but you seem to assume that you the latter needs to be done from inside the process that's the target of the operation. This is not the case.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: `hHook` does not need to be initialized; I could have written `NULL` in the call to `CallNextHookEx`. The first parameter in this call is ignored. Using `cout` is an attempt to inject text into an app, e.g., a text editor. It may be wrong, but a message box is not a solution. The idea is that when you're typing in text and press the hotkey, a string comes in as if fed from the keyboard.

Comment: @IInspectable: I agree that something has to be changed because it doesn't work. I believe that the apps on the PC do not observe the hotkey. But that's because I don't see any reaction. It is possible that the hotkey is caught, but text injection doesn't work. Injecting text might be done from outside the app, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: *"Injecting text might be done from outside the app, but I don't know how to do it."* - I'd linked to [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) previously. That's how you *"manipulate the UI by means other than standard input"*.

Comment: `cout` will very much not inject text into an app. Most likely, it goes into a bit bucket. `MessageBox` is just to confirm that your hook is actually running.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `MessageBox` is more than just a confirmation. It's a functional part of the hook implementation, since the thread that installed the hook must run a message loop for the callback to be called. That's what `MessageBox` does.

Comment: @IInspectable I meant to say, the OP could temporarily add a `MessageBox` call in their hook procedure just to verify that their hook DLL is in fact injected and receiving notifications. This was in response to the OP saying that "a message box is not a solution"; indeed, it wasn't meant as a solution to "inject text into another app" problem, but merely a temporary troubleshooting measure.

Comment: @IInspectable: I've briefly scanned the UI Automation documents but I see nothing that helps to inject text into desktop applications. Using a hook procedure is the right approach because it adds functionality to existing apps without changing them. I believe that text injection must be a part of the hook procedure. Or am I wrong and you coauld direct me to the APIs that may do the job for me? UI Automation seems to be about common controls that I've used in the WPF for quite some time.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Add Content to a Text Box Using UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/add-content-to-a-text-box-using-ui-automation) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834578/ui-automation-set-text-for-a-another-applications-textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hook procedure triggered with a hotkey using `ALT` must use hook `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. It does not work with the hook `WH_KEYBOARD`. The reason is that a hotkey using `ALT` must be caught early and stopped from proceeding further into the system.

Consequently, the call to `SetWindowsHookExW()` shown above is incorrect since it uses the hook `WH_KEYBOARD`.

The solution to the above problem is shown in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75581364/the-global-hook-procedure-doesnt-work-in-windows-11).

The main idea of the solution is to implement a hook procedure using hook `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and let it emulate keyboard input through the call to `SendInput()`. The advantage of this solution is that it works with any Windows control that can receive characters.